# How to group processes with the same name

Tags: ps

How to display list of all processes preferably (with no ps header line) where processes with the same name are grouped together?

```
ps -A | tail +2
```

prints the processes without the header but I can not find out how to group the processes that have the same name?

Answer (score 1):

```
ps|pr -t|cut -d" " -f3 |sort |tee output.lst
```

- ps -> gives the processes running
- pr-> paginating files -> suppress any header
- cut -> selecting particular column
- sort-> sorting any column
- tee -> stores as  well as displays

First, I have retrived the processes running through ps. Since ps gives a header so have used `pr -t` which will remove any header. After that, I have selected the third column of file since processes name are stored in third column through cut command. After that, I have sorted the result. It will bring processes with same name together. After that I have pipelined result to tee command.

Comment: I am not sure if I can understand your answer well. Maybe could you give more details?

Comment: is my answer wrong?

Comment: To decide, first I should understand it.

Comment: first, i have retrived the processes running through ps. since ps gives a header so have used pr -t which will remove any header .after that i  have selected the third  column of file since processes name are stored in third column through cut command .after that I have sorted the result . It will bring processes with same name together .after that i have pipelined result to tee command

Comment: @peterh          is it right?

Comment: No, I still can't understand.

Comment: I decoded and formatted your answer. [Read this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291370/1783163). Now it is already enough good. It seems, it deserved even an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
ps axhk comm
```

ax -- Display every process on the system.

h  -- No header.

k comm -- Specify sorting order by command.